# Linear Algebra - Tensor Products

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products, multilinear-algebra

> Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space over $\Bbb Q$ and $\bigwedge^kV$ be the $k$-th antisymmetric power. Let $\{ v_1, \dots, v_n \}$ be a basis of V. Define $$\pi: V^{\otimes k} \to \bigwedge^kV, \\ v_{i_1}\otimes \dots \otimes v_{i_k} \mapsto v_{i_1}\land \dots \land v_{i_k}$$
> and
> $$\iota: \bigwedge^kV \to V^{\otimes k}, \\ v_{i_1} \land \dots \land v_{i_k} \mapsto \sum_{\sigma \in S_k}\mbox{sgn}(\sigma)~v_{\sigma(i_1)}\otimes \dots \otimes v_{\sigma(i_k)}$$
> Where $S_k$ is a symmetric group in $K$ elements. 
>  a) Show that $\pi$ and $\iota$ are both $\Bbb K$- linear maps.  
>  b) Show that $\pi$ is surjective and $\iota$ is injective.  
>  c) Determine $\iota \circ \pi$.

---

For a) I was thinking maybe I could define a map $$\phi: V^k \rightarrow \bigwedge^k(V) \\ (v_1,...,v_n) \mapsto v_1\land v_2 \land \cdot 
\cdot \cdot \land v_n$$ which is clearly multilinear and then by the universal property there is a linear map: $$\bar{\phi}: v_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes v_k \rightarrow V^{\otimes k}$$ Since the composition of a multilinear map and a linear map is multilinear : $\pi =\phi \circ \bar{\phi}$.

Fir $\iota$ i have a similar method in mind.

Can someone tell me if this is correct and if not, maybe some hints?

c) I want to give the answer that it takes $\bigwedge^k V $ to $\bigwedge^k V $, but that seems to be such an easy answer i feel like thats not what the exercise wants me to show,

and as for b) can someone give me a few hints?

For b) I have an idea how to show $\iota$ is injective, but that is a property of the permutation, is that applicable here? So we show that the map is symmetric and then by the property of permutation its injective (I'm typing on my Ipad, typing everything out in Latex would take too long)..

Definition $V^r{\otimes}$: for every natural number $r$ the r-th tensor power of $V$ is defined to be $V^{\otimes 0}=K$ - $V^{\otimes r}:V \otimes_{K}…\otimes_K V$ with $r>0$

For $\land V $ it’s the usual definition from exterior algebra

Comment: For (a), the universal property seems to be a good idea to see that $\pi$ is linear, but you should better watch out how the map $\phi$ factors and how find $\pi$ in it. So $\pi$ will not be $\phi\circ\bar{\phi}$ (how you define $\bar{\phi}$ should also be overlooked).

Comment: Maybe it's dumb but can you not show (a) and (b) directly? Using the universal property is definitely more slick if you can get it to work.

Comment: for (c), note that $\iota\circ\pi$ should for sure be a map $V^{\otimes k}\to V^{\otimes k}$. So, if you regard $\bigwedge^k V$ as a subset of $V^{\otimes k}$ (depending on how you defined $\bigwedge^k V$) it indeed takes $\bigwedge^k V$ to $\bigwedge^k V$. But you also need to explain what it does on the rest of $V^{\otimes k}$.

Comment: for (b), you need to be a bit more precise what the problem is. Surjectivity of $\pi$ is rather immediate, is it? For the injectivity of $\iota$ i don't understand your idea.

Comment: To Derek Allums: Yes you can, but at least for $\pi$ using the universal property makes it into a two-line proof.

Comment: @nicrot000 Ouh yeah right the way i defined $\phi$ doesn't work.

Comment: @Derek Allums can you show it directly? by using that $f(a+b)=f(a)+f(b)$ method? Does that work here?

Comment: @nicrot000 actually i'm a bit confused, i thought it was multilinear, but its just linear. If I define $\phi$ to be $v_1\otimes ...\otimes v_k \rightarrow \bigwedge^k V$ that just feels like cheating-

Comment: No your $\phi$ was ok, but not the $\bar{\phi}$-definition. Also this last suggestion for $\phi$ is not a meaningful mapping.

Comment: Also I realized that your problem lacks some information. Note that not every element of $V^{\otimes k}$ is of the form $v_1\otimes\dots\otimes v_k$, but possibly also a linear combination of such "pure" tensors. But what is $\pi$ on such a linear combination? Just linearly extended? Then $\pi$ is linear by definition and your problem makes no sense. Maybe you can include in you post how $V^{\otimes k}$ and $\bigwedge^kV$ are defined for you.

Comment: @nicrot000 i have added a definition, but u r right the exercise isn’t precise enough.

Comment: Just saying that that it's "the usual" definition does not help much... So is $\bigwedge^kV$ the subspace of $V^{\otimes k}$ of antisymmetric tensors? Then $\iota$ is just the embedding and for sure linear. However, the problems for part (a) remain, what are the values $\pi$ and $\iota$ on linear combinations of pure tensors defined to be? Usually, they are defined to be the linear maps and thus is suffices to tell their values on a basis (which is what you do). But, as I said, this makes question (a) a strange question.

Comment: Where did you take this from? And are (b) and (c) ok now?

Comment: @nocrot000 Take what from? the definitions? from the script we have actually. I am still hopelessly stuck on all....

Comment: No I mean the problem. Was this a problem you got as a homework at university or what? In that case I would ask the person who gave you these problems.

Comment: And for (b), for the surjectivity of $\pi$ just take an element of $\bigwedge^kV$ and try to find an element of $V^{\otimes k}$ which is mapped by $\pi$ to that element in $\bigwedge^kV$. For the injectivity if $\iota$, once you know that this map is linear, it suffices to show that only one element of $\bigwedge^kV$ is mapped to $0\in V^{\otimes k}$.

Comment: For (c), try to write out $\iota\circ\pi$ explicitly.

Comment: @nicrot000 Yes this is an exercise from the university but the professor is known to not write students back, i wouldnt try that lol...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136594/discussion-between-jerry-cohen-and-nicrot000).